# Чи правильно вживати слово "напиток"

Tags: вживання-слів

Часто у розмові чуємо "смачні напитки". Чи правильно вживати це слово? Знайшла різну інформацію: у [Публічному електронному словнику української мови](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA) - "те саме, що напі́й", а в  [Довіднику з українського слововживання М.Волощак](http://nepravylno-pravylno.wikidot.com/all) - "напиток" неправильно вживати, а лише "напій".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насправді інформації не так багато щодо використання слова "напиток". Проте якщо приглянутись до [Словника української мови 1970-1980 рр.](http://sum.in.ua/s/napytok), то бачимо саме таку статтю:

> **НАПИ́ТОК**, тку, чол., розм., Те саме, що напій.
>
> На столі білий як сніг обрус, добірні страви й напитки (Леся Українка, III, 1952, 472);
>
> В домі було все приготовлене для гостя: в найбільшій кімнаті стояв стіл з наїдками й напитками (Анатолій Хорунжий, Ковила, 1960, 27).

Оскільки у словнику є позначка ***розм***., що означає розмовне, то це *слово все ж використовується у розмовному стилі*, проте у науковому чи офіційно-діловому його використовувати НЕ варто.

Також на [Офіційному сайті Української мови](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/slovnik_sinonimiv/n/napij/36-1-0-9994) подають:

> Синоніми до слова НАПІЙ: питво, пиття, (пре. хмільний) трунок, (гидкий) пійло, мн. ур. меди.

Синоніма ж "напиток" тут не згадано.

З Вашого дозволу, висловлю і свою позицію. Так, СУМ-20 не забороняє використання цього слова і навіть вказує на вживання його у розмовному стилі. Проте якщо у нашій мові є слово "напій", то краще оминати попереднє і використовувати саме його.
>

Comment: З іншого боку, якщо у нас є питомими слова *вжиток*, *податок*, *росток*, тобто, сама морфологія цілком питома, то чому б не вважати і *напиток* питомим, хоча spell checker його і підкреслює червоним?

Comment: З одного боку то так, але з другого, як на мене, більш милозвучно звучить "напій", аніж "напиток". Щодо пропонованих Вами слів, то тут нема куди діватись, ці слова, звичайно ж, питомі і суфіксів, які б замінити нема. Та й, зрештою, якби з’явилися зараз, сумніваюся, що нам би теж хотілося їх замінювати на звичні "ок".